# Is Forms Authentication Hash machine dependent?

Tags: asp.net, hash, sha1

I'm planning to use this piece of code in my Asp.net app

```
string strUserInputtedHashedPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(tbPassword.Text, "sha1");
if(strUserInputtedHashedPassword == GetUsersHashedPasswordUsingUserName(tbUserName.Text))
{
   // sign-in successful
}
else
{
   // sign-in failed
}
```

Is the Hashing machine dependent... In the sense, If I create some users in my development machine in my development DB...  Once I post both DB and Application to production environment with the user table, will the password for the users be same...

Hope I made my question clearly... Otherwise, please let me know..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash is encoded and decoded using the [machineKey in the machine.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9.aspx), if you want the key to work against all tiers, [make sure the keys in the machine.config files match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx).

This is basically the same problem you encounter with a web farm serving requests and validating each other's cookies...same solution.

Comment: I may sound stupid... But can I set up Machine key in Web.config... I dont think I will have access to Machine.Config of production machine...

Comment: @The King - Yes, this article describes how to do just that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx

Comment: Does anyone know where I can find any official documentation on this? I can't find any reference to the fact that the machine key is used in the MSDN docs for [HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.hashpasswordforstoringinconfigfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)