# Is the result of a md5 hash consistant or server dependent?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, md5

I am doing a md5 hash, and just want to make sure the result of:

```
md5.ComputeHash(bytePassword);
```

Is consistent regardless of the server?

e.g. windows 2003/2008 and 32/64 bit etc.

Comment: Are you doing an md5 hash to obscure passwords in your database? You shouldn't http://wblinks.com/notes/storing-passwords-the-wrong-better-and-even-better-way

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it's consistent, the [md5 algorithm specification](http://www.kleinschmidt.com/edi/md5.htm) defines it regardless of platform.

Comment: Except that I have seen some systems represent the output with upper case letters and some with lower case letters.  If you're comparing the string representation of the output, be sure and do a case insensitive comparison.

Comment: Are you mixing up the hexadecimal representation (-> String) with the MD5 value (-> Numerical) and do a string comparison? In that case it might happen that the valid hex chars are lowercase or uppercase - but the value is the same. In other words: If you compare 0xAa to 0xaA and consider the case relevant, then you are not comparing correctly and I'd consider that a bug.

Comment: Case is irrelevant here, since the method returns an array of bytes -- if he wants to convert it to a string representing the bytes as hexadecimal values then it would matter.

Comment: NOTE: The .NET implementation of MD5 in FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile generates a different hash per machine. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2249448/16387

Comment: @wizlb That's a password hash, which is not what MD5 (*Message Digest* 5) was designed for. There are good reasons to use use completely different hashing schemes for passwords: see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html

Answer (score 7):

MD5 is independent of operating system and architecture. So it is "consistent".

*However*, MD5 takes as input an arbitrary sequence of bits, and outputs a sequence of 128 bits. In many situations, you want strings. For instance, you want to hash a password, and the password is initially a string. The conversion of that string into a sequence of bits is not part of MD5 itself, and several conventions exist. I do not know precisely about C#, but the Java equivalent `String.getBytes()` method will use the "platform default charset" which may vary with the operating system installation. Similarly, the output of MD5 is often converted to a string with hexadecimal notation, and it may be uppercase or lowercase or whatever.

So that while MD5 itself is consistent, bugs often lurk in the parts which prepare the data for MD5 and post-process its output. Beware.

Comment: In C# / .NET you should specify which encoding you want to use -- for instance: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Blah"), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Blah"), Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("Blah")...

Answer (score 3):

The result of an md5 hash is a number.  The number returned for a given input is always the same, no matter what server or even platform you use.

However, the *expression* of the number may vary.  For example, `1` and `1.0` are the same number, but are expressed differently.  Similarly, some platforms will return the hash formatted slightly differently than others. In this case, you have a byte array, and that should be fairly safe to pass around.  Just be careful what you do after converting it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

MD5 Hashing is [system/time/anything except the input] independent