# MD5 hashing across platforms

Tags: mysql, vb.net, hash, md5

The website that I'm working on hashes login passwords with MD5.

A user's just forgotten his password so I'm on the database and I set the password to one of mine...

```
update users set pass = md5('thiS1smyp4s5w@rd')
where userid = 974
```

While the application uses MD5 hashing and I've set the password with Md5 hashing, I still can't log in with this user's details and I was wondering...

Are hashing algorithms the same across platforms or is there some difference between the way it's done in .NET as opposed to how it works in MySQL that would cause the hash values to differ?

Comment: Check out the answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435922/

Comment: And here is another very relevant post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249448/

Answer (score 0):

1. PLEASE don't use MD5 to hash passwords, it's not secure; [use BCrypt or PBKDF2](https://northernoptic.com/2015/09/10/the-lead-developer-lightening-talk-practical-web-security-junade-ali/).
2. The MD5 specification [should be consistent regardless of platform](http://www.kleinschmidt.com/edi/md5.htm), that said one thing that can cause issues is the fact that the letters in the hexits which are output maybe a different case (e.g. upper case instead of lower case), this only matters in case sensitive database queries.
3. That said passwords can be salted in order to prevent [Dictionary Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack), a salted hash is completely different to one which isn't salted thanks to the [Avalanche Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect).